# Parse json tags in C#

Tags: c#, json, xml, parsing, json.net

I have a json file that looks something like this:

```
{
"versionTitle": "Title", 
"sectionNames": [
    "Section1", 
    "SubSection", 
    "SubSubSection"
], 
"language": "he", 
"title": "Title, subtitle", 
"text": [
    [
        [
            "<big><b>some text </b></big>", 
            "<big><b>other text </b></big>", 
            <b>more text</> 
        ], 
        [
            "<big><b>text\n</b></big>", 
            "<small>other text <small>\n", 

        ],
```

I want to parse this into usable objects so that I can define the "big" tag as a title, and the "b" tag as regular text, etc., and style them appropriately.

I understand I need to do something like this to extract the json string:

```
  var json = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("jsonFile.json");

        var objects = JArray.Parse(json); // parse as array  
        foreach (JObject root in objects)
        {
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, JToken> app in root)
            {

            }
        }
```

However, how do I parse the tags and use the text within them, while styling the text according to the tag?

Comment: Your json is an `JObject` not `JArray` BTW: See http://json2csharp.com/

Comment: @L.B I'm new to json and don't understand it. Could you please explain more and guide me?

Comment: Get your model using the site link above... All you have to do now is `var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);` Now you have a concrete object to use....

Comment: @L.B But how do I differentiate between the different tags and use them appropriately?

Answer (score 1):

You need to parse them as XML because that is the what you have in the text field. You can use the built in XML parser to do that. 
[XmlDocument](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument(v=vs.110).aspx), it does get a bit more complex but you are using more then just JSON so that is going to be a given.

Reading from the script into xml.

`System.Xml.XmlDocument xml = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
xml.LoadXml( jsonFieldText /*"<big><b>text\n</b></big>"*/ );`

From there you can use [Xpath](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_syntax.asp) or loops to figure out your tree structure.